# Generar texto json desde una consulta en sql server con informacion completa

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net

actualmente tengo una consulta `select` la cual convierto a formato json usando `for json auto` pero resultado que se genera sale incompleto, y al intentar deserializar el string en C# tengo un error ya que la cadena de texto esta imcompleta

Comment: Hola y bienvenido a [es.so]. La pregunta esta un poco falta de información. Dale a [edit](/edit) para modificarla siguiendo las reglas de lo que es aceptado en este sitio: [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](/help/on-topic). También puede serte de interés realizar el [tour] y leer [ask]. Por otro lado, la salida de la ´for json`puede ser devuelta en varias filas [for json](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Ejemplos de como se consume en codigo .net [Salida for Json](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/json/use-for-json-output-in-sql-server-and-in-client-apps-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#use-for-json-output-in-a-c-client-app)

Comment: muchas gracias por tus sugerencias tendre en cueta tus comentarios a la hora de hacer otras pregunstas. en este caso en concreto tengo mi problemas es por la longitud de json generado y no por usar la consulta  del lado de una aplicacion cliente

Answer (score 0):

A veces la respuesta es mas sencilla de lo que parece, en mi caso fue asignarle el valor de la consulta a una variable y luego consultar la misma variable, asi:

```
DECLARE @JSONSTRING VARCHAR(MAX) = (SELECT ..... FOR JSON AUTO)
SELECT @JSONSTRING
```

al hacer esto, como le paso el valor de toda la consulta a una sola variable se pasa el todal de la cadena y no solo una sola parte como estaba sucediendo con la primera consulta